# error while running neo4j hello world program

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using this program from the source  https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.0/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java in Bluej

I have loaded the following .jar files 
neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.0-M05,
neo4j-kernel-2.0.0-M05, and
javaee

i have included javaee.jar from  glassfish/lib

I am getting the following error .plz help :(

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/TransactionManager
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase
    (GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase
     (GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase                         (GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.createDb(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:47)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.main(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:38)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.TransactionManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:197)
at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:69)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.createDb(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:47)
at EmbeddedNeo4j.main(EmbeddedNeo4j.java:38)
at __SHELL0.run(__SHELL0.java:6)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the jta library is missing. Download the .jar from
http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/transaction/jta/1.0.1B/
and add it to your project